# AC3D - No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, libraries, shared-library, multiarch

I just downloaded AC3D and extracted the zip in a folder in my home folder. I opened a terminal, CD'd to the folder and typed `./ac3d`. But I get the following error message every time:

```
bash: ./ac3d: No such file or directory
```

But the file is clearly there! I already made it runable so that couldn't be the case either. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**
@TheSchwa
I did. And it shows up so yes, it does get recognized.

@Nephente
Here you go. Output of `ls -l ac3d` is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ruben ruben 3758400 mei  1 23:34 ac3d
```

Output of `head -1 ac3d` is (abbreviated)

```
ELF@�   4�T94(44�4�44�4���o27o27@7����|_h�7h0h088HH�H�  P�td\�4\(\(PPQ�td/lib/ld-linux.so.2GNU �[...]
```

**Edit 2**:

Output of `dpkg --print-architecture`: `amd64`

Output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`: `i386`

Comment: Try entering the extracted folder, typing `./` and then `<tab>` twice to see if it's recognized.

Comment: Please change to the directory and append the output of  `ls -l ac3d`, and if the file really exists `head -1 ac3d` to your question. Do not put the output in a comment, but please edit your question.

Comment: I suspect, the problem is that you're running a 64bit Ubuntu without support for 32bit applications, which this binary is.  Could you append the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: Done that. Outputs are in EDIT2

Comment: Please add the download location of the zip

Comment: And please the output of `file ac3d`

Comment: @A.B. It is a 32bit binary. I could re-enact the problem in a Debian VM. Although i386 architecture support was enabled, the system lacked `libc6:i386`, hence the dynamic linker `ld-linux.so.2` is missing...  Installed the package and voila. The app still depends on some other libraries, but that's a different story. __tl;dr__: `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` should bring you a step forward.

Comment: Thank you Nephente! It works! Should I write an answer with the solution? Previously I could mark an answer but there aren't any given. So I do not know what I should do here.

Comment: That is actually a good question... I'd be happy to type one up though. Btw, if you put "@username" (quotes not necessary) in a comment, you'll notify the user about that comment. The author of a question or answer will always be notified about any comments though.

Comment: Alright, well, in that case. Be my quest. You were right about that lib. After installing it I got different error messages about missing libraries. But those were pretty straightforward because those were messages like "missing alibrary.so.3". All I had to do then was install them and then it worked. But I think those error messages can be different for other people.

Comment: Already did :-) Precisely because of that, I made the answer somewhat more general and included some more aspects of multi-arch and dynamic libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the binary is a 32bit executable and you're running a 64bit Ubuntu. That is not a problem, since Ubuntu offers support for multiple architectures.

If in doubt about the nature of an executable, or any file in general, the command

```
file <filename>
```

offers valuable information. If the command is not available, it can be installed through

```
sudo apt-get install file
```

In this case, it tells us among other information

```
ac3d: ELF 32-bit LSB executable[...]
interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

The interpreter is the bit of software responsible for loading all the shared libraries a binary needs to run. If it's missing, an application cannot run.

32- and 64bit executables need different interpreters and different versions of shared libraries. Fortunately Ubuntu (or more precisely Debian) introduced very sophisticated multi-architecture support some time ago<sup>[cit. needed]</sup>

To make sure the package system is prepared for another architecture, one can view the systems default architecture with

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

On a 64bit Ubuntu this will default to `amd64`.

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

prints out all other architectures the package system is aware of. For 32bit support, the output must contain `i386`. If it does not, one can add support with

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

It is necessary to update the package list afterwards

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The necessary libraries or packages in their i386 flavor can now be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install <package>:i386
```

More specifically, to install the needed interpreter, the installation of the `GNU C Shared Library` is indicated:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

This will in many cases make the binary in question execute, but of course there are many libraries an application can be dynamically linked against, that is depend on. These need to be installed in the same fashion. If a library is missing, the linker will give an error at execution

```
./ac3d: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: \
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

At this point one needs to find, which package contains this missing file.
If the corresponding package in the native architecture is already installed, one can search vi a`dpkg`

```
dpkg -S libGLU.so.1
libglu1-mesa:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
```

So we would need to install `libglu1-mesa:i386`. Repeat until all dependencies are satisfied.

But often a library is completely missing from the system. In that case, one can either search [Ubuntu's online package](http://packages.ubuntu.com) database, or install the utility `apt-file` and do

```
apt-file search <filename>
```

A very nice HOWTO on multi-arch support on Debian (same holds for Ubuntu) can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

**Extra:** The package `binutils` contains some pretty nifty tools to examine binaries. In particular it contains the `ldd` (List Dynamic Dependencies) util. It lists all the dynamic libraries a binary needs to run.

Example:

```
ldd ac3d
```

produces

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77b7000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf76ee000)
libGLU.so.1 => not found
libGL.so.1 => not found
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf76c0000)
libXmu.so.6 => not found
libXext.so.6 => not found
libX11.so.6 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xf76ba000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xf769e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75ac000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xf7566000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7549000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf739e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7381000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77ba000)
```

This way one can find out quickly which libraries are missing from the system.

Comment: @TheBoneJarmer You're very welcome. Btw. you also think my answer is well written and potentially helpful to others, you can also upvote it, in addition to accepting it. But that is of course entirely up to you ;-)

Comment: Done that! Nice job! But you know what still bothers me? I got it up and running with your help after almost 2 hours but just take a look what was required to do so. While for the same thing in Windows you just doubleclick the shortcut and be done with it. Besides that, the error message I got at first was confusing because it simply wasn't correct. I do not know if I can send a feedback item or anything to Ubuntu's developers because things like this just shouldn't happen.